# Store mysql subquery in a variable

Tags: mysql

Is is possible to store a mysql subquery somehow, if it will be used again as a subquery?  Presumably this would produce cleaner code as well as save parsing overheads.

For example in the following outer join

```
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo=='bar') ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo=='bar') ON t1.id = t2.id
```

It would be nice not to repeat `(SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo=='bar')`.

Comment: You can use  `ON t1.id = t2.id and t2.foo = 'bar'` instead of `(SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo=='bar')`. P.S only single `=` in mysql

Comment: You might use a view too

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. If MySQL had CTE (Common Table Expressions), you could use this:

```
WITH tmp AS
  (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo = 'bar')
SELECT * FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN tmp ON t1.id = tmp.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
  RIGHT JOIN tmp ON t1.id = tmp.id
```

If MySQL had `FULL JOIN` (which alas, it hasn't either!), you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  FULL JOIN (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo = 'bar') tmp
    ON t1.id = tmp.id
```

Answer (score 7):

Of course do it like this

```
SET @condition := (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo=='bar');
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (@condition) ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN (@condition) ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't think this is working.

Comment: Doesn't work if the subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: this doesn't work if the subquery has references to main query

Comment: Doesn't seem work if the subquery returns more than one column or row. I am on an old mysql, though.

Comment: That does work only if the `SELECT ...` returns a single item (in a single row). If it returns multiple columns *or* multiple rows then it doesn't work. MySQL 8.0.27.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed for the id value from a join table in my multi-insert!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has with function [since version 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). Making  @ypercube answer correct.

so now you can do for instance:

```sql
WITH subquery AS
  (SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.foo = 'bar')
SELECT * FROM t1
LEFT JOIN subquery  ON t1.id = t2.id
UNION
SELECT * FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN subquery ON t1.id = t2.id
```